# Facebook Graph API Conversation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I am using the GRAPH API Conversation endpoint to fetch the conversation between Messenger and Facebook pages. It gives the user information in the "to" and "from" fields. But the email of the user is not the original email. It gives values "1231321@facebook.com".
Is it possible to fetch the messenger user's original email address?

I have tried the Conversation API to fetch the messenger messages with user details but the user email is not the correct email value.

Comment: Only if the user logs in to your app and explicitly grants it the `email` permission.